Why most popular websites switched back to default scrollbar?
I have noticed that some popular websites (like: youtube, chatgpt) they implmented custom scrollbar and then again switched to browser default scrollbar.
My question is:
Is there any accessibility issue of using custom scrollbar?
If yes then, which ones?
If no then why popular websites don't use it?

Do you have examples of those customized scrollbars? I use mac/windows OS and different browsers and always appear the browser scrollbar.

@EmmanuelCuevas sometimes before ChatGPT added custom scrollbar like this(https://freeimage.host/i/dLuZxjI). YouTube also did samee but now they are using browser default scrollbar as you are able to see. My question is why they again switched to it?

sorry. I went to the Internet Archive, and I can't see any change in the ChatGPT or YouTube scrollbar; both sites use the browser's default designs. I have used micro-interactions on my projects but I didn't take a minute to think about change the style of it.
